# fb:login-button ignores scope?

Tags: facebook, plugins, scope

I changed my Facebook App to OAuth 2.0. Now the Login window ignores the user permissions.

The new login button code is as follows:

`<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="400" max-rows="2" scope="read_stream, publish_stream, email"></fb:login-button>`

when I use `perms` instead of `scope` it works.
I have oauth:true in FB.init(). In the app settings oauth2 is active.

Comment: I just noticed that it works if you set show-faces to false! How ridiculous is that.

Answer (score 2):

(Everything I did and learned was in an effort to be able to publish to a Facebook Timeline from a 3rd party website.  I don't know your motive/goal.  It might not be the same as mine.)

I am using JS SDK with javascript commands, not xfbml markup.

I am using the beta version of the JS SDK: set the host to `connect.beta.facebook.net` instead of `connect.facebook.net`

I have `oauth:true` in my `FB.init()` function.

I have app settings for OAuth 2.0 enabled at developers.facebook.com.

This is my FB.login():

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      // handle a successful login
    }
  },
  {
    scope: 'publish_stream' // I need this for publishing to Timeline
  }
);
```

One thing I did to debug this was to check the value of `FB._oath`.  If it is `undefined`, you have a problem.  If it is `true`, you can proceed to the next challenge.

So after lots of trial and error, I finally got `FB._auth===true`

Comment: PS - I was the one who responded to you on the Facebook developers group, before you suggested migrating this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: the fb:login-button is more trouble than it is worth.  Much better to wire up your own button and click handler with FB.logon as Teddy suggests.